# How do I resolve the Boot Camp error "Can't install windows support software."?

Tags: boot-camp

I have tried many times to download the Windows Support Software using BootCamp assistant on OSX Lion 10.7.4 ,every time after downloading about 650MB I get the error "Can't install windows support software."

What should I do?  I already installed Windows 7 and can boot from it, but with no network or video drivers not very usable.

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=892725

1) download http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-lion.merged-1.sucatalog

2) find in it the latest BootCampESD.pkg occurrence

3) use that link to download the pkg